# Vue-form-Wizard Plugin Remove Button in Vue js npm

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, formwizard

I have an issue which I've used `vue-form-wizard`,
The `first issue` I want to know if it is possible to remove the button? which is `Goback!` and `Go next`? I've install `vue-form-wizard`in my npm is there any way to remove it, or should I remove it inside `node mudules`? I just want to used this plugin for viewing and tracking

The `second issue` is when I used `start-index="2"` in `<form-wizard>` The layout will torn like the image below, is there any way to fix this?

[image]

- **Here's my code**

  ```
        <form-wizard color="#4466f2" start-index="2" title="Total Enterprise Value" subtitle="Accounting" back-button-text="Go back!" next-button-text="Go next!" finish-button-text="We're there">
            <tab-content title="Incoming">
             <div class="setup-content" id="step-1">
             </div>
            </tab-content>
            <tab-content title="Obligate">
             <div class="setup-content" id="step-2">
             </div>
            </tab-content>
            <tab-content title="Journal">
             <div class="setup-content" id="step-3">
             </div>
            </tab-content>
            <tab-content title="Certified">
             <div class="setup-content" id="step-4">
             </div>
            </tab-content>
        </form-wizard>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: I'd guess you installed it using `npm install vue-form-wizard` ... so, uninstall it using .... `npm uninstall vue-form-wizard` - that should fix the second issue too, but create a new one, because now you won't have `vue-form-wizard` therefore `<form-wizard>` will be an unknown component

Comment: by the way, the documentation suggests you do `:start-index="2"` note the `:`

Comment: @Bravo Thanks for your suggestion , so it means there's no way to remove the button in `vue-form-wizard` ? the solution is to use other plugins?

Comment: oh, no idea - you want vue-form-wizard, but you don't want the buttons ... maybe the [documentation](https://github.com/BinarCode/vue-form-wizard/tree/master/docs#footer-slot) will help